# Получить вторую половину строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.Есть строка наподобие этой:
`"Истомин Денис - Попырин Алексей 0-0(3-2) 40:15 adv"`

Как убрать первую часть строки чтобы получилось 
`"0-0(3-2) 40:15 adv"` ?
Желательно regex.

Answer (score 4):

Делаем все только одним регексом, без доп программной обработки:

```
 (?<=[\w\s+])\d+.*
```

(?<=[\w\s+]) - lookbehind называется,   находит последний символ текста и пробел после него и исключает его из мэтчинга
\d+.* включает все что начинается с цифры после текста и включает его в мэтчинг, квантификатор звездочка жадный, так как нам конец строки  нужен

  не забудьте экраны проставить если в джаве, я их убрал для чистоты понимания. Хотя скажу сразу, лук назад при работе с не фиксированным кол-вом символом в регексе чуть медленее, чем лук вперед. В джаве нет механизма реверса регекса, как в .NET.  если кто-то не знает что такое жадный квантификатор, скоро сниму видео на эту тему, а так же видео посвященное программе отладки регексов.
[image: Результат работы регекса]
Смотрите мой канал посвященный регуляркам, пишите вопросы в комментах.[Пересечение и вычитание в регулярных выражениях java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZIxx8PNcMo&t)

Answer (score 2):

С первой цифры и до конца

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d.+");
    String text = "Истомин Денис - Попырин Алексей 0-0(3-2) 40:15 adv";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    String newText = "";
    while(m.find()) {
        newText += text.substring(m.start(), m.end());
    }
    System.out.println(newText);
}
```

Или можно так, чтоб наверняка.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+-\\d.+");
```

Со счёта и до конца.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно newText = text.split(regex);???

Comment: Например первая часть у меня получилась newText = text.split("[0-9]")[0];

Comment: Ну это совсем другой метод. Он разбивает строку по шаблону. В данном случае получается массив 
[Истомин Денис - Попырин Алексей , -, (, -, ) вввв, , :, ,  adv]. Вторую часть из него в принципе не вытащить.

Comment: Можно сделать так: newText = Arrays.toString(text.split(" "));, т.е. разбить по пробелам. Получится массив слов без пробелов. Если вам так удобно, можно с этим работать.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз.